# FAQ in "Good news everyone!" email doesn't mention private beta invitations

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta

The FAQ about private beta in the "Good news everyone!" email states

> Q: Who can access the site during the private beta?
>
> A: **Only** the
>   388 people who committed to it.
>
> ...
>
> Q: What else?
>
> A: The minute the **public beta** opens, **invite your
>   friends**. Spread the word via Twitter, blogs, and email far and wide.
>   Hang out on the site answering incoming questions during the first few
>   hours so that newcomers understand what a great experience a working,
>   popular Stack Exchange site can be.

(Presumably, "invite" here means "encourage your friends to join" rather than "send them an invitation")

But the private beta website has

> Invite Fellow Experts
>
> email a **private beta** invite to:
>
> message (optional):
>
> Send invite

Perhaps inviting experts to the private beta is a new feature, and the FAQ about private beta hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380195/208518), this email was updated to better reflect the current Area 51 process. Among other changes made, the bits quoted now read:

> Q: Who can access the site during the private beta?
> A: The $NUM_COMMITTERS$ people who committed to it will get an invitation to sign up, just like this one. They can invite fellow experts, and anyone can access the site as long as they create a profile on it.
>
> ...
>
> Q: How can I help the site succeed?
> A: During the private beta, ask and answer questions, create appropriate tags, edit posts for clarity and grammar, and vote. You should also invite fellow experts: spread the word via Twitter, blogs, and email far and wide. Hang out on the site answering incoming questions so that newcomers understand what a great experience a working, popular Stack Exchange site can be.